# Java and UseLargePages

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

We have a number large heap (6-12Gb, some larger) JVM servers. I'm considering configuring Linux for large page support. As usual YMMV, but for those of you that have availed yourselves of this capability, how much difference did it make for your situation? How important is the choice of page size specified in LargePageSizeInBytes?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 5):

I have collected a number of resources for large pages, for Java and other environments / applications / OSes / hardware (MySql, Linux, Sparc, AMD).
Some people get very significant increases in performance.
http://zzzoot.blogspot.com/2009/02/java-mysql-increased-performance-with.html
[Note I last updated this page 2010/07]